# Detect if its Ubuntu Linux OS in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to create a makefile that will compile my objects and name them according to the Linux distro (e.g. Suse, RedHat, or Ubuntu).  How can I detect if the OS is Ubuntu or not?

Comment: got it working? (since you deleted your comment :D)

Comment: yes, I changed the OS var to be "shell lsb_release -si" and now it works well :). Thanks you for your answer!

Comment: +1 for the funny title. (hint: Makefile and Make file mean totally different things.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We use `cat /etc/lsb-release` for identifying the Ubuntu release:

```
sh-3.2$  cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=8.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=hardy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS"
```

For other releases it might be

```
ls /etc/*release
```

Gentoo, RedHat, Arch & SuSE all have a release file: http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/release-files.html These is a complete script in the link ;)

---

Example code for operation system, architecture and version for Ubuntu type systems:

```
OS=$(shell lsb_release -si)
ARCH=$(shell uname -m | sed 's/x86_//;s/i[3-6]86/32/')
VER=$(shell lsb_release -sr)
```